# Why doesn't Flexbox alignment work on placeholder pseudo-element?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, textarea

I'm trying to align the `::placeholder` pseudo-element using Flexbox.

I'm aware of traditional ways of alignment, like `text-align` for inline alignment, the `line-height` hack for block alignment, or simply absolute positioning. I am not interested in those.

Flexbox works fine for aligning `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements (try it!). But somehow it doesn't work for aligning the `::placeholder` pseudo-element of `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements.

Why?

```css
textarea {
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  /* should put it center center */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  /* should put it top center */
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Some text"></textarea>

<input placeholder="Some text" />
```

Comment: use textarea::placeholder in css and try

Answer (score 0):

Think that flexbox only works when parent have specific width

you can do it with

```
textarea{
        display: flex;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

or if you want just placeholder to be center use position absolute like this:

```
    textarea{
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    textarea::placeholder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 35%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I clarified the question stating that I'm not interested in other solutions but why Flexbox doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally centralize it via `text-align` and vertically centralize it via `line-height`.

```css
    textarea {
      height: 10rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    textarea::placeholder {
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 10rem;
    }
```

```html
    <textarea placeholder="I'm not centered"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. I clarified the question stating that I'm not interested in other solutions but why Flexbox doesn't work.

Comment: @philmcole horizontally you can center the text via text-align.

Comment: @philmcole text-align works for the actual text as well for horizontal centering.

Comment: @philmcole justify-content works if there is a parent element which is flex and it justifies the child items if there is space left. Apparently it is not applied on placeholders of textboxes.

Comment: ...which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @philmcole I guess the reason is that the textarea's inner text is not a tag.

Comment: No. As stated in my revised question, for `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements it works fine.

Comment: @philmcole those are pseudo-elements. While the palceholder is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Flexbox works fine for aligning `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements (try it!). But somehow it doesn't work for aligning the `::placeholder` pseudo-element of `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements.

In a flex container, `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are treated as children of the container. Therefore, they are flex items and can accept flex properties.

Note [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS) from MDN documentation:

> In-flow `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements are now flex
> items.

In a flex container, neither the `placeholder` attribute or `::placeholder` pseudo-element can be flex items. Therefore, they ignore flex properties.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain this. MDN doesn't quite satisfy me though. I'm wondering if this is somehow mandated by the CSS spec? I couldn't find anything...

Comment: If what is mandated? `::after` and `::before`? Well, here's a conversation between the spec authors. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867454

Comment: Or why placeholder is excluded from flex layout? In that case, practically all attributes are, as far as I can tell. No need to create a rule for just one of them.

Comment: I see. I was under the assumption `::placeholder` was an pseudo-element like `::before` and `::after`. It didn't occur to me that setting it's contents through an attribute somehow needs to restrict the way it can be styled by CSS. Seems to me like more of a remnant of the times before Flexbox and that since Flexbox was created nobody took a look at. I can understand this because `::placeholder` is probably low on the list of priorities. Although I think it'd be still worth to align it easily without hacks like in the old days...

Comment: I think the area of CSS3 technologies (such as flex and grid) applying to HTML attributes and CSS pseudo-elements is mostly unexplored and undeveloped. For now, the spec developers seem to have settled on the behavior of `::before` and `::after`, but not much else.